# jQuery .click() not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass, removeclass

I have looked through a few of the other stackoverflow questions about the .click function not working but none of them seem to help me. I have my imports of the jquery libraries.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my jquery and im not sure why this isnt working. I have it so it waits till the page is loaded to attempt to run. And i have the class on that element but it doesnt register the click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('nav.product-description-nav ul li a').click(function() {
                $(".product-description-nav ul").find($('li a.active-product-selection')).removeClass('active-product-selection');
                $(this).addClass('active-product-selection');
            });
        });
```

Here is my navigation with that i am trying to add the classes to and remove them on the click.

```
<nav class="product-description-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="active-product-selection">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Request A Quote</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I always have trouble with jquery and I think i am referencing everything ok i know the remove class works if i add that statement to a function called on a click but i dont want to have onclick functions within the a element. Is my syntaxed messed up or maybe im referencing the jquery libraries wrong?

This is the answer to my problem

```
$(document).on('click','.product-description-nav a',function(){
            $(".product-description-nav a").removeClass('active-product-selection');
            $(this).addClass('active-product-selection');
        });
```

Comment: remove one of your imports

Comment: You're including two different versions of jQuery. Without [serious precautions and care](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), that's not going to work well (or at all).

Comment: Try not to nest so hard. Give the a or li a class and use that as the selector. Remove the top extra jQuery include.

Comment: Once that's sorted out, your `find()` isn't going to work - you're looking for an `li` within an `li`.

Comment: Iv removed all the imports except the google import for jquery and that didnt work. Iv also changed the find function to look through the ul instead of the ul li and that didnt work either.

Comment: _"look through the ul instead of the ul li"_ What do you mean by that? What code did you try?

Comment: My code is edited for that comment now its $(".product-description-nav ul").find($('li a.active-product-selection')) instead of $(".product-description-nav ul li").find($('li a.active-product-selection'))

Comment: But... Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it is working fine for me. When I click one of the options, it removes the class from whoever had it and adds it to the one I clicked... Are you sure your js is correctly included?

Comment: I didnt know that it mattered that the navigation was included using php i thought it included it before it attempted jquery but i guess the document.ready function couldnt determine that. so had to use the .on function my question is updated for the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the entire hierarchy at all times. You can simply remove the class from all `a` tags within the `nav`, then add the class back to `this`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav.product-description-nav a').click(function() {
    $("nav.product-description-nav a").removeClass('active-product-selection');
    $(this).addClass('active-product-selection');
  });
});
```

```css
.active-product-selection {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="product-description-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active-product-selection">Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Options</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Downloads</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Request A Quote</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'v tried to use this and its still not working for me. Does it matter that my navigation is being called into my page by a php include statement?

Comment: Not necessarily. It *would* matter if the elements were added, later, by Javascript. Since the example here works, it would be helpful to show an example with correct JS that does *not* work.

Comment: They would be added later. The elements are added after the body onload since i have them being added based on the url parameters and have them loaded using jquery .load() I would post the entire code but its alot of code and alot of it is sensitive information for my job that i cannot show. I have it down to the basics

Comment: "The basics", except for the part where "they are added after the body onload", which changes things significantly. If the elements don't exist when `$('nav.product-description-nav a').click(function() {` is called, the click handler is never installed. There's nothing to install it *to*. You could work around this by calling `$(document).on('click', 'nav.product-description-nav a', function()...` instead. Still guessing, since we still can't see any code that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sweet! The $(document).on() function worked. I havent ever used this so does the on function run once the document includes the element?

Comment: Something like that. Read [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for the details, I don't want to misinform.

Comment: Ok thank you. I didnt know that the includes didn't get loaded before the jquery tried to run. Im still kind of new to jquery but starting to get the hang of it thank you for your patience.